# Generic driven customizable bus width on port of symbol

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, bus, xilinx-ise

I've created a VHDL module in ISE and generated the corresponding schematic symbol.  I would like the buses in the symbol to be variable width, specified using an attribute in the schematic layout editor.  A whole-project DRC is okay, but when I attempt to synthesize the top level schematic it throws an error for each port which I've specified as 'variable'.  I built this up from common sense and examples listed [here](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/12062.htm) and [here](http://m.eet.com/media/1151615/vhdl_1.txt).

**VHDL for module:**

```vhdl
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity BUS_SWITCHER is
    generic (
        WIDTH : integer := 1 -- Structure
    );

    port (
        A : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        B : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        X : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        Y : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (WIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        S : in STD_LOGIC
    );
end BUS_SWITCHER;

architecture Behavioral of BUS_SWITCHER is
begin
    process (A, B, S)
    begin
        if S = '1' then
            X <= B;
            Y <= A;
        else
            X <= A;
            Y <= B;
        end if;
    end process;
end Behavioral;
```

**Symbol for module (in schematic connected to 4 x 256 wide buses):**

[image: Screenshot (via Imgur)]

**Properties window:**

[image: Screenshot (via Imgur)]

**Error log:**

```
ERROR:DesignEntry:20 - Pin "A(0:0)" is connected to a bus of a different width.
ERROR:DesignEntry:20 - Pin "B(0:0)" is connected to a bus of a different width.
ERROR:DesignEntry:20 - Pin "Y(0:0)" is connected to a bus of a different width.
ERROR:DesignEntry:20 - Pin "X(0:0)" is connected to a bus of a different width.
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are instantiating this module, you need to wire it up to a `std_logic_vector` of equal width.  So in this case, your higher level module needs to create an intermediary signal that is std_logic_vector(0 downto 0).  If you want to convert that to a single `std_logic` you can do that as follows:

```
single_bit <= entire_vector(0);
```

I try to avoid length 1 std_logic_vectors for this reason, they can be a pain.

Comment: Maybe I didn't word my question very well, I'm looking to create a *variable* width port.  The fact that it is single width `std_logic_vector` in the images is because that is what I set the default value to.  The problem is that this default value of the generic is not being overridden by the attribute specified on the instance.

Comment: @MTCoster Try removing your default value in your entity and in your package file (if you use one).  Only give it an override value when you instantiate it.